# Отобразить данные с JSON в Django в таблицу

Tags: django, json, jinja2

Всем привет. Я выгружаю JSON файл с CRM системы. Беру оттуда такие данные: номер заказа, сумма заказа, список заказаных товаров, дата. Хочу эти данные сделать в виде таблице на странице сайта(Django). Вопрос: как лучше реализовать это? Я предполагаю сделать так: все эти данные из JSON перенести в базу данных и уже из базы данных выгрузить в Django шаблон с помощью Jinja.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Да без разницы как

Comment: если надо хранить в бд, чтобы потом таблица грузилась быстрее - может быть тоже бд, тут зависит от того насколько большой файл и насколько быстре отработает json.loads и выгрузка из бд. в теории из бд в результате будет быстрее и эффективнее. если небольшие файлы, и мало строк - то можно файл распарсерить

Comment: Тут нет обязательного правила хранить именно в БД. Я вижу проблему в "Названии товаров", так как в нем хранятся несколько значений. И я вот думаю, можно ли в одной ячейке хранить несколько "Названий товаров": джинсы, кроссовки, кепка и.т.д

Comment: в django в postgres есть ArrayField. А раньше такие пробелмы решались созданием модели названий, чтобы исключить дублирование данных. сейчас наверное тоже

Comment: а проблемы я не вижу, просто при выводе в других колонках указываете `rowspan`. выводите все названия , а после с `rowspan` остальные данные